# Grids Visibility before the execute function

Tags: wpf, grid

I've a problem with visibility grids. The code below:

```
        private void btnInstall_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        grid3.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        grid4.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        Install();
    }
```

The problem is that grid3 and grid4 visiblity changes only when the function finished and it should be before the execute function. Why is this happening? I try add Thread.Sleep, try, finally, but without success.

Comment: Till the function ends the UI thread will be blocked. If you want to update the UI and Run your Install method in background, create a thread and use to execute the Install method.

Answer (score 0):

Till the function ends the UI thread will be blocked. If you want to update the UI and Run your Install method in background, create a thread and use to execute the Install method.Refer the below code.

```
 private void btnInstall_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        grid3.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        grid4.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { Install(); });
    }
```